# Is storing information in RAM more secure than on Disk?

Tags: malware, windows, android, ios

I realize neither is foolproof, of course. I would just like to confirm my thought that it's harder for an attacker to get a memory dump than to copy from disk/flash-storage or that malware just tends to copy from disk more than it does from RAM. So that wherever possible, it's better to have the apps I write avoid getting sensitive material on disk, and better to keep it in memory until needed.

This is not about a specific scenario, it's the general rule that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of nuance. Each process *should* only be able to access the area of memory which is assigned to it by the kernel. With file/disk access each process may be able to read files owned by their calling user, files marked as readable for the calling user's group and world-readable files.

That said, in the case of virtual memory and suspend/hibernate actions there is the possibility that the sensitive data which an application is dealing with in memory is written to disk by the system. *(**EDIT**: It's been pointed out that newly allocated process RAM will be zeroed by the kernel in most situations, so processes which are killed are not likely to leave much remanence in RAM. It is, however, possible for a process which freed a malloc'ed variable to have leftover data swimming around in it's address space if that same process later malloc's a new variable, but that's not as relevant here. The other points still apply)* Lastly, if the process which is handling the sensitive data happens to have a buffer overread vulnerability then that would allow an attacker to provide that process with a crafted input which would allow that attacker to read the current memory space of the process. Including the sensitive data...

**I'd recommend keeping any sensitive data encrypted until the time at which it is needed.** Normally this means keeping it encrypted on disk and decrypting it at time of use, but it may also be feasible to keep it encrypted in memory and decrypt at time of use (assuming the decrypting keys are not also stored in memory).

Comment: As a follow-up, I'd look into recommended sensitive-data-handling procedures for each platform you're planning on developing for -- they vary between OS. Here's some notes for iOS: https://books.nowsecure.com/secure-mobile-development/en/coding-practices/securely-store-sensitive-data-in-ram.html

Comment: Even if it's encrypted, the app must have a way to decrypt it in order to use it, so that would be in memory/disk as well.

Comment: Right, but if you're using say iOS or Android then there are system-provided secure keystores which offload that responsibility to the Operating System.